# Authenticate a custom web service from browser

Tags: javascript, authentication, browser, oauth, jwt

I have a requirement of encrypt my post data sending from browser to a restful web service (https)  and authenticate it properly. I was going through the different available options and came across different terms like JWT, Oauth 2.0

I have a few questions in mind after reading jwt and oauth2.

1) jwt is a combination of header, payload and a secret - is that a reliable approach.
2) Oauth2.0 2 legged approach - generating access tokens and use it till expires - How would be the authentication of generating tokens

Could you guys throw some lights on best ways to protect the data and authenticate it properly.

tia

Answer (score 0):

> I have a requirement of encrypt my post data sending from browser to a
> restful web service (https) and authenticate it properly.

The encryption of your post data will be performed by using HTTPS, but about authentication you could use OAuth 2.0 if case of posting data in behalf of a user for example (the Resource Owner per RFC 6749).

In case you aren't performing any operation in the name of a Resource Owner, you could use the Client Credentials grant type as per RFC 6749: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4 (but remember that your client application needs to be registered against an Authorization Server that should be recognized by a Resource Server - your restful web service - to perform token validation).

Regarding the usage of JWT in such a scenario, it could be used to be a self contained access token that the Resource Server (your restful web service) should be able to inspect. Considering this kind of token validation, both Authorization Server and Resource Server must be aware of JWT.

Just another thing: remember that OAuth 2.0 isn't an authentication protocol. It is an authorization framework that can be used to build an authentication protocol (OpenID Connect is an example).